# excel 2010, look up blank cells in two columns, return text in corresponding different column

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Here is a screenshot of my data:

[image: Data]

I want to search B4:B40 and C4:C40 and find all cells that are blank for both specified ranges. If blank in both ranges, return the text in the corresponding row in column A. Ideally, the output could be combined and it could list something like 8:00-2:00.

here is what i have so far:
    `=INDEX('C:\Path\to\other\worksheet\[Blank Schedule Grid.xlsx]Susan'!B4:B40, MATCH("",'C:\Path\to\other\worksheet\[Blank Schedule Grid.xlsx]Susan'!B4:B40,0),'C:\Path\to\other\worksheet\[Blank Schedule Grid.xlsx]Susan'!B2)`

Am I on the right path?

Comment: So what would be the output from the data above?

Comment: it doesn't quite work, it just gives me no error, but just a blank cell?

Comment: I did not ask what the formula was doing or not doing.  Please, tell me using the data from your example, what would the desired output(s) be?  It may be easier to skip to the end then try and fix what you have.

Comment: the desired output would use the text in column A. so for example B25 and C25 do not have any text in them, so 4:30 should be the output. Now ideally if there were multiple rows that satisfy this, it could list them as a range (4:30-6:30 for example) but I don't know if that is possible

Comment: @William Scott makes the impossible possible ~_^

Comment: So as I see it you would want, `1:00`,`1:30`,`4:30`, and `12:00 mid` as your returns.  The idea of concatenation would be more difficult.

Comment: Did Scott just use the word `difficult`? Who are you and what did you do with Scott?

Comment: @ScottCraner yes, that would be the correct output. And concatenation would be more difficult, that is what i figured so for now I just want the basic down. ->findwindow legendary huh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you want is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$18:$A$40,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$18:$A$40)-ROW($A$18)+1)/(($B$18:$B$40="")*($C$18:$C$40="")),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

I will let you put in the workbook and sheet references.  They are only needed on the Ranges.  Do not put them on the Range references in the the ROW() functions.  They are only there to return a number and it does not matter the sheet to which they reference.  Just make sure that the ranges themselves match.

[image]

The concatenation with the workbook references would make the formula long and unwieldy.  To do that VBA would be the best route.

---

**Edit:**

Got bored and decide to put in your workbook and worksheet references:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('C:\Path\to\other\worksheet\[Blank Schedule Grid.xlsx]Susan'!$A$4:$A$40,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$4:$A$40)-ROW($A$4)+1)/(('C:\Path\to\other\worksheet\[Blank Schedule Grid.xlsx]Susan'!$B$4:$B$40="")*('C:\Path\to\other\worksheet\[Blank Schedule Grid.xlsx]Susan'!$C$4:$C$40="")),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Comment: thanks scott! i put this in though and it gives me .25? (it is supposed to be run as an arrary correct?)

Comment: @William That just means you are pulling the actual *time value* and need to format the cell to `h:mm` or `h:mm AM/PM` as preferred.

Comment: @William no it does not need the Ctrl-Shift-Enter to validate.  AGGREGATE() is a non CSE array formula.

Comment: oh, sorry, don't know how i didn't catch that. And to get multiple outputs like you did on your sheet? It just returns 6am which is great, as expected, but can the one formula output all the values at once? i really appreciate your help!

Comment: @William You want all the values in one cell?

Comment: @ScottCraner it seems you have to run the formula for each time you have a blank cell in both? One formula can't handle this and output to say "A4:A20" of the worksheet where the formula is?

Comment: No not in Excel.  Each cell has to have a Formula.  Put the Formula in A4 and drag down to A20.  It will then update as the data changes.  Do not paste the same formula in each cell.  The last `Row(1:1)` is dynamic and will change as the formula is filled down.  The IFERROR() will take care of the times that there are not enough results to fill all the cells. @William

Comment: thank you thank you thank you! you da man! really appreciate it! makes sense now!

Comment: @ScottCraner one last problem I'm running into is an incorrect display of time. When the result of the function goes beyond 12:59pm it displays as 1am even though the source sheet shoes 13:00 or 1:00pm? any ideas?

Comment: @William no, it should put in what is in Column A.  Are you sure that column A is 13:00 not 1:00 AM.  Change the Format to "General" in Column A.  IF it is PM it will be above .5 if not it is AM. and you may need to fix the values in Column A.

Comment: ok, it is fixed now. it seems the formula doesn't work unless the sheet is actively saved after each change, then and only then can it read it.

Comment: Yes by using the file path in the the formula it is looking at the file in the folder not what is open.  Therefore it is looking at the last saved data.  It is a trade off.  You can look at the active data if you don't mind opening the file every time you want to link to it.  Or you have to save the data before the changes will be read. @William

Comment: gotcha! I'll keep it with accessing the saved data.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want all the values in a single cell or in a new column?

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(B18), ISBLANK(C18)), A18, "")
```

Assuming your data starts in A18 (as per the screenshot), you can put this in cell D18 and copy all the way down.

Comment: thanks for responding, but the formula is in a separate workbook entirely, hence the remote paths.

Comment: and sorry, to clarify, my data is in B4:B40 (as per my above code) and in C4:C40. I want the input to read those two columns and an output to be "true" for each row in that range if there is data in that row in either column B or column C. If it is true, I want it to output the corresponding value in column A

Comment: `output to be "true" for each row in that range if there is data in that row in either column B or column C`
So you want to return the value in column A if there IS data in either B or C?
`If blank in both ranges, return the text in the corresponding row in column A`

Comment: if blank in both ranges, do not return anything. if there is text in either one, then return the text that in is in Column A on the same row

Comment: Glad you found the answer, but your comments here are the opposite of your question and it's comments.